# ipa extension on iphone app

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPhone/iPad development. I wonder why apple use ipa extension instead zip (which is file actually) for mobile apps. 
Here is output from file app.ipa

> app.ipa: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

Why don't they just use zip ?

Comment: Why did id software use .pak instead of .zip? Probably because the intent is that is is not to be unzipped by the user.

Comment: Also, why `.jar` and not `.zip`, why `.c` and not `.txt`… =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use it to avoid people unzipping it, simple as that. IPA-files are a bit harder to open, therefore "more secure". Also, Apple likes to do things *their* way.

I don't see any disadvantages with using .ipa over .zip really.

Comment: I don't think “harder to open” has anything to do with the reason, and indeed `.ipa`s are _easier_ to open for the most common purpose (uploading to an iOS device) because the handler can be assigned independently of the general `.zip` handler. (As for Apple doing things “their way”, that's certainly true, but this is not an example of that. Doing things their way would not be using zip but some proprietary compression.)

Answer (score 2):

`.ipa` signifies that it's not just an archive intended to be extracted, but rather an iOS app, with specific data and layout inside what just happens to be a zip archive.

Edit: Note that it's not particularly unusual to define a custom extension to indicate that a file fulfills additional specifications (and/or has a specific “purpose” other than that of the more general file format). For example, `.c`, `.java`, etc are all text files, but they are not *just* text files but text files with a very specific format (C and Java programming language, respectively).

Similarly to `.ipa`, Java ARchives (`.jar`) are also zip files but they fulfill a more specific purpose and contain more specific data than “just any” random `.zip`. As it happens, Android `.apk` files are even more specific `.jar` files, and consequently also `.zip` files… But as the purpose and format become more specific, it makes sense to change the extension to indicate this.

(As an additional benefit, opening these more specific extensions may cause the operating environment to launch a more specific program, e.g., an IDE instead of a simple text editor, or iTunes instead of an unarchiver. I don't see this as the primary purpose for having a more specific extension, however.)

Answer (score 1):

It is because iTunes handles *.ipa/*.ipsw files but not zip files
Same as *.app/.bundle, they are folders actually, using a different extension can change the default open reaction.

Comment: Exactly. Imagine if iTunes wanted to open any .zip file. Or if your unarchiving app wanted to open any iOS app or firmware files.